# How'd I do on this card matching game?

Tags: javascript, html, game, css, playing-cards

I threw this together for a web dev class I am taking at school and I thought I'd throw it up to see what criticism I could get on my JavaScript, design, whatever.

Bonus points if you can tell me how I can fix the bug with users clicking to quickly and more than two cards flipping at a time.

Disclaimer: I know that I left the cheat in so you can get the first set of cards. I didn't want anybody going crazy before getting that first set.

Here is the [Card Matching Game](http://mattgowie.com/im2401_ex03/).

```
// Author: Matt Gowie
// Created on: 10/01/12
// Project for Web Dev 2400

$(document).ready(function(){

  var cardArray = 
  [
  'd-ace', 'd-ace', 's-ace', 's-ace', 'c-ace',
  'c-ace', 'h-ace', 'h-ace', 'd-king', 'd-king',
  's-king', 's-king', 'c-king', 'c-king', 'h-king',
  'h-king', 'd-quen', 'd-quen', 's-quen', 's-quen', 
  'c-quen', 'c-quen', 'h-quen', 'h-quen', 'd-jack',
  'd-jack', 's-jack', 's-jack', 'c-jack', 'c-jack',
  'h-jack', 'h-jack', 'd-ten', 'd-ten', 's-ten', 
  's-ten', 'c-ten', 'c-ten', 'h-ten', 'h-ten',
  'd-nine', 'd-nine', 's-nine', 's-nine', 'c-nine',
  'c-nine', 'h-nine', 'h-nine', 'd-sev', 'd-sev',
  's-sev', 's-sev', 'c-sev', 'c-sev', 'h-sev',
  'h-sev', 'd-six', 'd-six', 'joker', 'joker'
  ];
  var cardsToFlip = [];
  var matches     = 0;
  var score       = 0;
  var multiplyer  = 10;


  fillBoard = function(){
    $('.board').html('')
    var rowCount = 1;
    var colCount = 1;
    var card = '<div class="card back"></div>';
    for(var i = 1; i <= 60; i++ ){
      var cardPick = Math.floor(Math.random() * cardArray.length);
      var cardClass = cardArray.splice(cardPick, 1)[0];
      var $card = $(card).data('cardClass', cardClass);
      // For debugging!
      if(cardClass == 's-ace'){ $card.addClass('debug'); }
      var $container = $('<div class="container">').attr('id', "card" + i)
        .addClass("row" + rowCount).addClass("col" + colCount);
      var $cardContainer = $('<div class="card-container">')
        .data('cardSide', 'back').append($card);
      $container.html($cardContainer);
      $('.board').append($container);
      colCount += 1;
      if(i % 10 === 0){ rowCount += 1; colCount = 1; }
    }
  }();

  $('.container').bind('click', function(){
    var cardId = $(this).attr('id');
    if(cardsToFlip.length <= 1 && cardsToFlip[0] !== cardId){
      flipCard(this);
      cardsToFlip.push(cardId);
    } else {
      if(cardsMatch()){
        console.log("Cards Matched!");
        $(cardsToFlip).each(function(i, e){
          $("#" + e).html('')
        })
        matches += 1;
        $('.matches').html(matches);
        score += 10 * multiplyer;
        $('.score').html(score)
        $('.mult').html('10X')
      } else {
        console.log('Multiplyer: ' + multiplyer);
        if(multiplyer != 1){
          multiplyer -= 1;
        }
        $('.mult').html(multiplyer + 'X');
        $(cardsToFlip).each(function(i, e){
          flipCard($("#" + e));
        })
      }
      cardsToFlip = [];
    }
  });

  var cardsMatch = function() {
    var cardOneClass = $('#' + cardsToFlip[0]).find('.card').data('cardClass');
    var cardTwoClass = $('#' + cardsToFlip[1]).find('.card').data('cardClass');
    if(cardOneClass === cardTwoClass){ return true; } else { return false; }
  }

  var flipCard = function(container) {
    var classToRemove, classToAdd, flipDir;
    console.log("flipCard called");
    var $cardContainer = $(container).children('.card-container');
    var $card = $cardContainer.children('.card');
    var cardSide = $cardContainer.data('cardSide');
    var cardClass = $card.data('cardClass');
    if(cardSide == 'back'){
      classToRemove = 'back';
      classToAdd = cardClass;
      flipDir = 'rl';
      $cardContainer.data('cardSide', 'front');
    } else {
      classToRemove = 'front ' + cardClass;
      classToAdd = 'back';
      flipDir = 'lr';
      $cardContainer.data('cardSide', 'back');
    }
    $card.css({ 'background-color': '#AB0000' });
    $card.flip({
      direction: flipDir,
      onBefore: function() {
        console.log("classToRemove in onBefore: " + classToRemove);
        $card.removeClass(classToRemove).addClass(classToAdd);
      },
      onEnd: function() {
        $card.css({ 'background-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)' });
      },
      speed: '750',
      color: '#AB0000'
    })
  }


});
```

Comment: Always useful to send the code through [jshint](http://www.jshint.com) and see what warnings you get (I see a bunch of missing semi-colons and one implied global). Oh, and it's spelled "multiplier" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't had the time to go over all your code in detail, but here are a few ideas.

Overall, my first suggestion would be to separate the various pieces into several more functions. Keep the HTML-manipulation (building, styling, flipping cards) separate from the more abstract parts (score calculation, the card repetoire, etc.). In the same way a game of chess can be played by players with a board made of pebbles and chalk - or without a board entirely - the *logic* of this game is independent of its *presentation*.

You have several discreet steps here: Make a deck of *n* pairs, shuffle the deck, then make the actual HTML. Each of these steps should be a separate function. This is basically *top-down design*: Figure out what are the overall steps are, then figure out how to do each step.

I'd also say you could be more abstract, just in general. For one, you don't really have to care about the actual suit and value of a card - at least not in your JS; the point is just that there are *n* number of discreet pairs. It doesn't need to be playing cards. You have 30 pairs, but I say *n* because the exact number is irrelevant. There just needs to be at least 1 pair.

So far you might have something like:

```
function buildDeck(numberOfPairs) {
  var i, deck = [];
  for( i = 0 ; i < numberOfPairs ; i++ ) {
    deck = deck.push(i, i);
  }
  return deck;

  /* re the comments, you could alternatively do this:
  for( i = 0 ; i < numberOfPairs ; i++ ) {
    deck = deck.push(i);
  }
  return deck.concat(deck);
  */
}

function shuffleDeck(deck) {
  var rand, shuffled = [];
  while( deck.length > 0 ) {
    rand = Math.random() * deck.length;
    shuffled.push(deck.splice(rand, 1)[0]);
  }
  return shuffled;
}

function buildCards(deck) {
  var i, l;
  for( i = 0, l = deck.length ; i < l ; i++ ) {
    buildCard(deck[i]);
  }
}
```

The `buildCard` function isn't implemented yet, but it would be responsible for making the HTML for a single card, and adding it to the board. That step could also be divided into more discreet steps: Build a blank card, give it its specific value, append to document, etc..

Note that the deck is just an array of numbers at this point. The deck can be any size (that's divisible by 2 anyway), since it's not based on a pre-defined, finite list of aces, kings, queens, jacks, etc.. Now obviously, each card needs to *look* different, but that can be accomplished in the CSS alone. Simply give each card a class like `"card_" + value` (kinda like you're already doing for the `id` attribute, except IDs must be unique, whereas there must be exactly 2 cards with the same value-class), and only deal with the "class_x → image_y" in the CSS.

Of course, you could further encapsulate the deck-logic in a `Deck` class and so on, and so on. But that's for another day.

Hopefully this gives you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely go about implementing this and put up and update a bit later. I'd upvote your answer, but it seems I cant do that since I have 11 reputation. I appreciate the help though

Comment: Question: Why did you use the array method concat in buildDeck and then push in shuffled? Looking up the concat method it seems, at least at first glance, that it is equivalent to push? Is there a reason behind that? Thanks again.

Comment: @Gowie47 You're right; the use of `concat` could and should be `.push(i, i)`. Or you could push just 1 `i`, and concat the array with itself afterwards. I'll update my answer

Comment: @Gowie47 re your first comment: Don't update the code in your question. If people update their questions, everyone would have to rewrite their answers too, or they'd lose their meaning. So leave your original code in the question untouched (you can add new stuff to the question, though). As for upvoting, thanks, but there's no need for that since you asked the question, which means you - and only you - can checkmark the answer that helped the most. Wait and see if someone else posts something, but sooner or later you have to checkmark an answer in order to mark this question as answered.